# When a spade is not a spade

Tags: terminology, education, big-list

Typically, when one sticks an adjective in front of a noun, the resulting noun phrase refers to a subclass of the things that the bare noun refers to.  For example, a red truck is a special type of truck.

There are certain standard exceptions, notably when the adjective serves a negating or broadening function.  For example, a near success is not a success, and a would-be intellectual is not an intellectual.

Some of the most confusing terms in mathematics are those which violate the above principles.  Three (admittedly rather arcane) examples that come to mind are:

- A quantum group is not a group
- A perverse sheaf is not a sheaf
- A Boolean-valued model is not a model

What are some other examples?  I feel that there are probably many examples that I've gotten so used to that I no longer notice the "illogicality."  I think it would be useful to compile a list of these so that people who teach math can be aware of them, and point out the possible confusion to students.

Note that examples involving adjectives such as "pseudo," "quasi," "almost," etc., don't really count in my book because these adjectives are widely understood to negate or partially negate the noun in question.

**EDIT:** Here is another example that occurred to me:
A [fractional ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal)
is not necessarily an ideal.

Comment: skew field${}$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng : Hmmm...I'm inclined to say no, because "skew" feels to me like a negating adjective. "Skew-symmetric" isn't symmetric, for example, and that seems normal to me. But maybe I've just gotten used to it!  (And someone could object to my example of "perverse sheaf" since "perverse" sounds negative.)

Comment: Manifold-with-boundary is not (unless the boundary is empty) a manifold, a persistent source of confusion.

Comment: A bit off the subject, but this linguistic phenomenon arises in other domains:  An "English horn" in music is not a horn at all (it is a woodwind).  A "Jew's harp" is not a (traditional) harp.

Comment: I would not include Boolean-valued models: they are a straightforward generalization of the Tarskian notion that I’m perfectly happy to call models.

Comment: A partial function on $X$ is not (necessarily) a function on $X$. (I'd be surprised if this wasn't already a question on MO somewhere...)

Comment: I would discount "partial" as being in the set the OP excluded, illustrated by "pseudo," "quasi," and "almost."

Comment: @JohnHughes : That's a good one! (Even though technically it's not quite in the form "<adjective> <noun>".) Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: An "imaginary number" is anything but.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Just as a "real number" is not... real. If anything, I'd argue all numbers are imaginary.

Comment: Perhaps, "When a black spade is not a spade" for the title? exclusion list should have : "anti", "semi", "generalised", "approximate", "no-where", "non/not". Certainly an electric piano is a "generalised" piano, its creation forcing english to backtrack and from then on say "acoustic" or "classical" or "traditional" piano.

Comment: To add on the comment of @Brian, models *are* Boolean-valued models.

Comment: In the same way, a minor planet is not a planet that is minor. The term "minor-planet", with an hyphen, would have made it clearer that is must be read as a block.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : If X is Y, it doesn't follow that Y is X. I understand the point that you and Brian are trying to make, but the point is that "model" is defined in many texts as, in effect, "two-valued model." Here's an analogy: Is a curve a set of points? An algebraic geometer might say no, a curve isn't *really* a set of points. Nevertheless, in many texts, a curve *is* defined as a set of points, and that does cause confusion.

Comment: "Paeudo-" is explicitly negatory; it is Greek for "false". So  a pseudometric is a "false metric", and nobody would expect a "false metric" to be a true metric.  Similarly "quasi" is Latin for "as if" and a "quasimetric" is something that may not be a metric but that behaves _as if_ it were a metric.

Comment: @MJD: The etymologies, however, are largely irrelevant: it is how they are used in English that matters. In this case that usage largely retains the Greek senses, so the modifiers do belong on the list of exclusions.

Answer (score 11):

Manifold-with-boundary is not (unless the boundary is empty) a manifold, a persistent source of confusion.

Also: "delta function." Sigh.

Others please feel free to add your contributions.

Comment: +1 for the sigh.

Answer (score 7):

A Hilbert-basis is not a basis.

Comment: I remember being confused by this one. In particular I couldn't puzzle out why a Hilbert space with a countable Hilbert basis could have an uncountable basis as a vector space.

Answer (score 6):

A rational function is typically not a function.

Comment: Huh?? "In mathematics, a rational function is any function which can be defined by a rational fraction, i.e. an algebraic fraction such that both the numerator and the denominator are polynomials." (from Wikipedia)

Comment: @DavidGStork Typically if you say "a rational function on $U$" you mean "a ratio of [formal] polynomials on $U$". The denominator could well vanish at points of $U$, so the ratio is really only a partially defined function on $U$. Calling something a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ doesn't literally mean it's a function on $\mathbb{C}$--same issue. The Wikipedia definition is a bit naive in my book.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork $X$ and $X^2$ are distinct rational functions on $\mathbb{F}_2$ (the two-element field), i.e. distinct elements of $\mathbb{F}_2(X)$. But $x \mapsto x$ and $x \mapsto x^2$ are the same element of $\mathbb{F}_2 \to \mathbb{F}_2$: they're functions that map the same inputs to the same outputs. You can gloss over the distinction between rational functions and the induced (partial) functions when working with infinite fields, but not with finite fields: there distinct rational functions can induce the same function, and e.g. $\forall x, F(x) = G(x)$ does not imply $F = G$.

Answer (score 5):

The signed measures, the outer measures, and the inner measures are supersets, not subsets of the measures.

Not sure if this counts, but ergodic theory concerns a great deal more than ergodicity or ergodic theorems.

I don't think there's anything unusual about this.  It's common for adjectives or noun pairs to create meanings other than by restriction.  I don't recall the linguistic terms for the different roles such pairings created, but I've come across some of them.

Further, in math, you can pick a phrase that kind-of sort-of feels right, and then just give it a definition, in virtue of which it thereby becomes precisely correct.

(fwiw, I've always suspected that a several things that aren't entirely intimately connected are called "ergodic" because people thought that "ergodic" sounded cool.)

Answer (score 4):

A right inverse is not necessarily an inverse! Likewise, if a functor is left exact there is no guarantee it is exact. Watch out for left/right!

Answer (score 4):

This phenomenon is sometimes referred to as the "red herring principle".  This phrase is used, for example, on a [page on nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/red+herring+principle) (a wiki for category theory).  Knowing the phrase might help you find more examples.

Examples are common in category theory, and I'm surprised that the nlab page doesn't list very many of these.  Here are some I know of:

- There are various concepts called "[something] category" that are not (in general) categories, e.g. enriched category, internal category, double category.  If you're including prefixes, you can add bicategory, tricategory, n-category and multicategory to that list.
- Various concepts in category theory can be weakened or made lax (laxened?), and a "weak [something]" or "lax [something]" is not normally a "[something]", e.g. a weak n-category is not an n-category, a weak limit is not a limit, a weakly initial object is not an initial object, a lax monoidal category is not a monoidal category, a lax functor is not a functor, etc.  These kinds of examples can get pretty esoteric, e.g. lax trimodification.
- A simplicial set is not a set; likewise a globular set is not a set.  There might be similar examples with other types of presheaf.

Additionally, I think there's an extra level of implicit subtlety to the question.  In maths, the answer to the question "is a red herring a herring?" is not a simple yes or no – as I see it, there are three possible cases:

1. A red herring is a herring with the property of being red.
2. A red herring is a herring equipped with some extra structure that makes it red.
3. A red herring is not a herring.

I think case 2 is a grey area, neither a definite yes nor no.  To give a mathematical example, a monoidal category is a category equipped with a monoidal product (a piece of extra structure).  Thus a monoidal category has an underlying category, but strictly speaking perhaps one shouldn't say that it *is* a category, in the same way that one wouldn't say a group *is* a set.  Depending on whether you think case 2 is a yes or a no, this might help you find more examples.

Answer (score 3):

Almost Upper Bound is an example that is a broadening function. Even more confusing that the word "almost" is typically not broadening. Caused me quite a headache a few days ago (see here: [Why is an almost upper bound named so?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820682/why-is-an-almost-upper-bound-named-so?r=SearchResults))

Answer (score 3):

I wrote [a blog post about this](https://blog.plover.com/math/partial-function.html) a while back. Examples include:

- A partial function is not (in general) a function
- A contravariant functor is not a functor
- A hom-set is not a set
- A skew field is not a field
- A snub cube is not a cube
- A quantum group is not a group
- A Gaussian integer need not be an integer
- At one time, affine spaces were known as "affine vector spaces", despite not usually being vector spaces.

As Mars says in another answer, this is common outside of mathematics also.  For example, a toy ball is a ball, but a toy fire engine is not a fire engine.

Comment: I like "snub cube." In a similar vein is the adjective "truncated." I also like "Gaussian integer." There's also "Eisenstein integer" or even "algebraic integer."

Answer (score 0):

An ill-defined function is not a function.