# Inverse function of $f(z)=\frac{z^2-1}{z+1}, z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem**if $f(z)=\frac{z^2-1}{z+1}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Find the inverse function of $f$.

Solution: It has sense if $z \neq -1$ by the denominator, then $f(z)=z-1$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}-\{z=-1\}$ then the inverse function is $f(z)=z+1$. Am I right?

Comment: "if $f(z)=\frac{z^2-1}{z+1}$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$" doesn't work. The expression isn't defined on all of the prescribed domain. Some remove removable singularities implicitly, but then it should at the very least be stated as a general principle earlier in the text.

Comment: This somehow depends on the context. Sometimes people will automatically identify a function with its holomorphic extension.

Comment: Suppose that we don't know holomorphic extension. Then that function doesn't have an inverse function, right?

Comment: If we don't extend the function implicitly (no need for holomorphic extension, continuous is enough for a single point), then as written it isn't a function. How could it be an invertible function if it isn't a function?

Comment: @Arthur: how can something be a manifold-with-boundary if it isn't a manifold? :)

Comment: @JohnHughes The same can be said about rational functions. But not invertible functions.

Comment: I know; I was just being whimsical. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3829311/when-a-spade-is-not-a-spade/3829339#3829339 for more fun examples.

Comment: I'm going to nitpick your notation here. It may not seem important, but sloppy notation can lead you into making errors as you will confuse even yourself by it. First, $\{z = -1\}$ is not proper set notation. The "$z =$" serves no purpose. The proper notation is $\Bbb C - \{-1\}$  Second (and more important), $f(z)$ cannot be both $z -1$ and $z+1$. The inverse of $f(z)$ must be called by something different than the function itself. The most common notation for the inverse of $f(z)$ is $f^{-1}(z)$,

Comment: If $-1$ is not in the domain of $f$, what can you say about the range of $f$?